# Running .NET Core 2.0 app on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Tags: .net-core

I am a newbie in Linux.

I read that .NET Core 2.0 is not supported on Ubuntu 32 bit OS. But as .NET Core is open source I can build the .NET Core (CoreCLR and CoreFx) on Ubuntu 32 bit to support on 32 bit Ubuntu. So I started to build CoreCLR following instructions at   https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/linux-instructions.md

I was successful in building the CoreCLR on it and generated an output in ../bin/Product/Linux.x86.Debug folder which is as per my desire.

Now i want to run a Self Contained .NET Core app using corerun executable (generated as output), properly specifying the PATH, CORE_ROOT and CORE_LIBRARIES environment variables following the instructions at https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/workflow/UsingCoreRun.md

But i got an error with message **coreclr_initialize failed - status: 0x80004005**.

I am not sure why this is coming.

Then I thought that perhaps I have to build CoreFx also and tried to build that also but not able succeed in it.

Will anyone please help me in this. Also please tell me whether I am going in right direction or not??

Comment: seeing the logs might be helpful > export PAL_DBG_CHANNELS="+all.all"

Comment: I'm going to assume that it has something related to this part of your question: `.NET Core 2.0 is not supported on Ubuntu 32 bit OS`. If possible, I would upgrade to a 64 bit OS as 32 bit Linux distributions are not supported.

Comment: @IvanZaruba please find the logs at https://1drv.ms/f/s!AojB8HgSXc4RaVvg0BWZyYb5pOs

Comment: @JamieTaylor I want to do it on 32 bit OS. On 64 bit I have checked that it is working fine.

Comment: As .NET Core is not supported on 32 Linux distros, I would say that it's not possible for a reason. Even the Azure Linux containers for .NET Core run 64 bit OSs.

Comment: But in the instructions for building coreclr and corefx there is clearly mention that we can cross compile them for arm, x86 etc. That's why I am trying for this.

Comment: The [instructions that you link to](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/linux-instructions.md) don't mention building for x86. They do mention building for ARM, but not for x86. Is there a different set of documentation that you are referring to?

Comment: @JamieTaylor, I got my mistake. Actually I was cross compiling dot net core for arm on Ubuntu 32 bit OS. But now I got that it is not possible. Cross compilation is also possible only on 64 bit OS.